# How can Kőnig's Lemma be expressed in Monadic Second-Order Logic of 2 Successors?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, proof-theory, decidability

I read the following on Wikipedia's page on [Monadic Second-Order Logic of Two Successors (MS2S)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S2S_(mathematics)):

> Weak S2S (WS2S) requires all sets to be finite (note that finiteness
> is expressible in S2S using Kőnig's lemma).

Is this statement an error?  I would think that only [Weak Kőnig's Lemma(WKL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics#Weak_K%C5%91nig%27s_lemma_WKL0) would be expressible in MS2S since it is restricted to binary trees whereas [Kőnig's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_lemma) is not limited to finite tree width.  If it is possible to express the full Kőnig's Lemma, how would one do so?  If not, how would one express WKL in MS2S?  I looked at the [axiomatization of S2S](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434659/axiomatization-of-s2s) but wasn't sure how to go about expressing WKL using it or another representation such as an infinite tree automata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would think that only Weak Kőnig's Lemma(WKL) would be expressible in MS2S

You're slightly misreading the passage - the point is that Konig's Lemma can be used to show that finiteness is definable in MS2S. (That said, you are right that even WKL would be enough.)

Here's the idea. First, note that in MS2S we can define the ordering on $2^{<\omega}$: we have $\sigma\preccurlyeq\tau$ iff every predecessor-closed set containing $\tau$ also contains $\sigma$. From this **and (weak) Konig's Lemma** we can define infiniteness: $X$ is infinite iff every downwards-closed set $Y\supseteq X$ contains a chain with no greatest element.

The point is not that KL, or WKL, is somehow being expressed in MS2S; rather, we are using (W)KL in the metatheory so to speak in order to prove something about the strength of MS2S. This is in fact nontrivial: over general structures, monadic second-order logic is *incomparable* with weak monadic second-order logic despite the name of the latter. (To see why this is plausible, consider an equivalence relation with infinitely many infinite classes *and* infinitely many classes of each finite cardinality.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Out of curiosity, would it be possible to define WKL in MS2S?  It seems they deal with very similar structures.  What would prevent one from showing that every infinite binary tree has an infinite path (I think that is a correct statement of WKL, please correct me if I'm wrong)?  I'm still learning about MS2S, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @hatch22 What does "define WKL in MS2S" mean?

Comment: Sorry for the poor word choice.  I meant can WKL be expressed in MS2S, such that the fact that the infinite binary tree has an infinite path is something that MS2S could represent as a theorem of monadic second-order logic?  Define is the wrong word.  Again, I'm still learning about MS2S and was simply struck by the fact both WKL and MS2S seem to relate to infinite binary trees.  Could MS2S express WKL in a way somehow similar to how MS1S can express a superset of theorems of Presburger Arithmetic?  If I'm way off base here just let me know.

Comment: @hatch22 Interesting question. I'm not sure, but see my edit.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't think $\mathsf{WKL}_0$ is conservative over $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ for $\Sigma^1_1$ sentences. $\Pi^1_1$ sentences yes, but for $\Sigma^1_1$ sentences an instance of WKL for a recursive counterexample like the Kleene tree will be a $\Sigma^1_1$ sentence that $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ cannot prove.

Comment: @BenedictEastaugh Quite right, I'm embarrassed!

Comment: The Wikipedia article on $\bf{KL}$ mentions that the typical proof of $\mathbf{KL}$ and I assume also $\mathbf{WKL}$ relies on proof by contradiction {PBC) and thus is not considered constructive.  Since $\mathbf{RCA_0}$ is typically considered capturing the nature of constructive mathematics and doesn't use PBC (as far as I know despite using classical logic), might the decidable nature of MS2S allow it to use PBC arguments to express $\mathbf{WKL}$, or is a bad line of argument?

Comment: @hatch22 $\mathsf{RCA_0}$ has nothing to do with constructive mathematics, it allows proof by contradiction as normal. (It's connected rather with **computable** mathematics, which is rather different.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I was perhaps mislead by the table given for the [Big Five Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics#The_big_five_subsystems_of_second-order_arithmetic) on Wikipedia, which shows $\mathsf{RCA_0}$ as corresponding to constructive mathematics (not intuitionism, but Bishop style constructivism).

Comment: @hatch22 Yeah, that's a very poor correspondence.